# Tabs in Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I am trying to convert some of my old applications into new Windows Store App design. Some of these applications use `Tab`s to represent multiple functionalities of the applications. For example, I have a simple English-German dictionary with two main functionality:

- Translate English to German
- Translate German to English

each represented in a separated `Tab`.

I have looked around various applications in Metro style and found no equivalent to `Tab`s. 
It is possible to create `Tab`s manually (using buttons and ...) but they probably had a reason for not including such thing in default elements.

What's the proper way to design such concept in Metro?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating tabs in WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737117/creating-tabs-in-winrt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement "tabs" in two ways:

1. Use the top app bar, like Internet Explorer
2. Provide on-screen buttons in the header of the app (and style them to look like Pivot items in Windows Phone 7)

However, I believe that tabs should be used for independent activities. In your case, most users would want to easily swap from one translation to another. So, I recommend that you implement an interface similar to http://www.bing.com/translator/ or http://translate.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the FlipView control. A typical example showing where this is used is the control used for navigating screenshots in the Windows Store. You can make use of buttons (or whichever control you choose) to change and track the currently displayed item in the flipview.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview