# Tab Control In WinRT WINDOWS 8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, tabs, pivot, windows-rt

I am New To windows 8 App Development. I am creating one Windows Tablet Application in Visual studio express 2012 for windows 8. Is it possible to run this app to tablet because i am developing application in visual studio 2012 for windows 8???
I want to add Tab Control to my app like Windows Phone 7 & 8 supports pivot control like i have attached one image here.[image] i want to add same controls in my app as image shown.
one tab control and into each tab there is another tab control. how can i add it to  my app?? please help me

Comment: You can refer following answer:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737117/creating-tabs-in-winrt][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737117/creating-tabs-in-winrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend switching to Visual Studio Express 2013. 2012 should work for 8.0 though. There is no tab control in WinRT XAML. There is a grouped `GridView` or `Hub` control that serves similar purposes though. If you'd rather go with the more classic Zune Software-like tabbed interface - you should put a bunch of restyled `RadioButtons` in a horizontally oriented `StackPanel` like [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample.Windows/Views/Controls/TreeViewTestPage.xaml) and a few overlaid `Grids` underneath, then switch visibility of these panels based on the checked `RadioButton`.